# PHP comparison is not returning correct result

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm looking up a value in a SQL table. The table is returning the value "text", but when I run a comparison on it I get false. Is there a reason this would return false?

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $valType = $row['valType']; //Result: "text"

    if("text" === $valType) {
        $result = "true";
    } else {
        $result = "false";
    }
    echo $result; //Result: "false"
}
```

Thanks to the help of @Rocket Hazmat, I found my issue by using var_dump($row['valType']). It was a case sensitivity issue.

Comment: What does `var_dump($row['valType']);` show you?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: It's not returning anything.

Comment: It's supposed to echo something to your screen.  It didn't?

Comment: So, what does `var_dump($row)` yield? Typo, perhaps?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: Yeah it didn't echo anything. It's pretty strange behavior.

Comment: @Boldewyn: This also didn't return anything.

Comment: If `var_dump` didn't echo anything, then how did your `echo $result;` work?  Are you sure this `while` loop is even running?

Comment: Also, check the source of the page, do you see anything from the `var_dump` there?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: Silly me, I was printing but my AJAX wasn't collecting what was printed. I just went to the page directly and here is what it printed for the value.  "Text" ["valType"]=> string(10)

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: Annnd looking at that I think that I see the issue. CASE SENSITIVITY!!! Thanks for your help with this, var_dump completely slipped my mind!

Answer (score 0):

In your code example $valType is not "text", it is something else. See below example.

```
<?php
    $valType = "text";
    if("text" === $valType) {
        $result = "true";
    } else {
        $result = "false";
    }
    echo $result; //Prints "true"
?>
```

This could be shortened like this:

```
<?php
    $valType = "text";
    echo ("text" === $valType ? "true" : "false"); //Prints "true"
?>
```

Comment: This will return "true", but then I'm not getting the data from my SQL table.

Comment: justin your question is now misleading because comparison works, you need to troubleshoot the query since now you narrowed down the issue.